# turning urls into subdomains?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, subdomain

i have this url

http://www.example.com/user.php?user=solomon

i want to convert this into

http://solomon.example.com

how can i do this!! thanks :))

p.s. im using plesk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Plesk's capabilities, but on a LAMP server, you need to use Apache's `mod_rewrite` module and have a wildcard DNS setup for *.example.com through your DNS provider (either your registrar or your hosting provider).

Your `.htaccess` for your virtual host will look like this:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) user.php?user=%2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks,i have root access, how can i set a wildcard DNS thanks :))

Comment: Setting up a wildcard DNS for example.com (*.example.com) has to be done by whomever controls your DNS records.  i.e. in your WHOIS record for example.com, the nameserver records point to the DNS server(s) that control your DNS zone; this is likely the same place where you registered your domain (GoDaddy.com, networksolutions.com, etc.).